# what's the Max. volume size of one single file on linux ext4?

Tags: android, linux, filesystems, ext4

If I have a 32 bits linux system and the filesystem is **ext4**, what's the Max. volume size of **one single file** which I want to storage into the ext4 ? And how to calculate the file size ?

As we know , the android use the linux kernel , so how about on the android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to all of your questions are on the [Ext4 wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4).  Specifically:

> **Max. file size:**    16 TiB (for 4k block filesystem)

A quick google search seems to indicate that Android uses ext4 as well.  I don't know any details - maybe somebody will come along with more specific information.

Comment: Does the Max. file size stand by one single file size? I am not sure about that .

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.